# Multinomial Combination

Tags: combinatorics

There are 8 new teachers that have to be places in 4 schools (one school can get all the teachers).

How much combinations are there?

I am sure I need to use the Multinomial formula, but there are so much combinations like:

$8\choose2,2,2,2$  and $8\choose6,0,0,2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give more information, can a school be assigned no teachers or must each school get at least one? If each school can be assigned no teachers, then you may want to represent the number of teachers in school $i$ where $1 \leq i \leq 4$ as $X_{i}$ (note each $X_{i}$ is a non negative integer) and look for solutions to $$ X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+X_{4}=8.$$

Comment: Ok look at my post, can you find the number of solutions to that equation?

Comment: it is $8+4-1\choose4-1$ but the answer is 65,536

Comment: Ok sorry i was assuming you couldn't distinguish between teachers, silly!

Comment: The answer is simply $4^{8}$ for each of the 8 teachers there are 4 possible schools to which he or she can be assigned

Comment: thanks! what do you mean by "i was assuming you couldn't distinguish between teachers"
each teacher is a different person

Comment: Sorry i put that down to it being a monday morning! The best way i can describe it is, perhaps the question instead said that 8 identical computers were going to be delivered to 4 schools. In this case we are simply counting the number of computers delivered to each school and the solution would be $\binom{12}{3}$.